# Python MVC style GUI Temperature Converter

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, model-view-controller, tkinter

```
#The view (GuiTest.py)
import tkinter
import Controller
class MyFrame(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, controller):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.pack()
        self.controller = controller
        #Output Label
        self.outputLabel = tkinter.Label(self)
        self.outputLabel["text"] = ("")
        self.outputLabel.pack({"side":"right"})
        #Entry Space
        self.entrySpace = tkinter.Entry(self)
        self.entrySpace["text"] = ("")
        self.entrySpace.pack({"side":"left"})
        #two convert buttons
        self.convertButton=tkinter.Button(self)
        self.convertButton["text"]= "Fahrenheit to Celsius"
        self.convertButton["command"]=self.controller.buttonPressed2
        self.convertButton.pack({"side":"left"})

        self.convertButton2=tkinter.Button(self)
        self.convertButton2["text"]= "Celsius to Fahrenheit"
        self.convertButton2["command"]=self.controller.buttonPressed1
        self.convertButton2.pack({"side":"left"})
        #Quit button
        self.quitButton = tkinter.Button(self)
        self.quitButton["text"] = "Quit"
        self.quitButton["command"] = self.quit
        self.quitButton.pack({"side":"right"})
```

## The Model

```
import tkinter
import GuiTest
import Controller
class Convert:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fahrenheit = 0
        self.celsius = 0

    def convertToCelsius(self, fahrenheit):
        self.celsius = float((self.fahrenheit - 32)) * (5/9)
        return self.celsius

    def convertToFahrenheit(self, celsius):
        self.fahrenheit = float((self.celsius * (9/5))) + 32
        return self.fahrenheit
```

## The Controller

```
import tkinter  
import GuiTest # the VIEW
import Counter    # the MODEL

class Controller:
    def __init__(self):    
    """
    This starts the Tk framework up
    """
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.model = Counter.Convert()
        self.view = GuiTest.MyFrame(self)
        self.view.mainloop()
        root.destroy()

    def buttonPressed1(self):
        result = str(self.model.convertToFahrenheit(self.celsius))
        self.view.outputLabel.config(text = result)
    def buttonPressed2(self):
        result = str(self.model.convertToCelsius(self.fahrenheit))
        self.view.outputLabel.config(text = result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = Controller()
```

## Question

Everything is working in my Temperature converter GUI program, however whatever value I type in the Entry, it always passes a 0 value, hence when i convert the input to fahrenheit it will be 32 and -17.7778 for celsius. What am I doing wrong or how to I get the Entry value in the View to my Controller? Thank you!

Comment: You did `root.destroy()` immediately after `self.view.mainloop()`. Are you sure that's the way to go?

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure about that Tiger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two mistakes here:

1 - In your `Counter.py` file and in your `Convert` class methods, you are not return the right variables, instead of `return celsius` you should return `self.celsius` and same goes for `self.fahrenheit`

2 - In `Controller.py` file:

`self.view.outputLabel["text"] = self.model.convertToFahrenheit(celsius)` 
This will not update the `label`, instead you should do something like:

```
result = str(self.model.convertToFahrenheit(float(celsius))) #need to convert to string
self.view.outputLabel.config(text=result) #update the label with result
```

Same goes for `buttonPressed2` method

**EDIT-1:**

Better change your equations in your `Convert` class to return correct `float` result:

`self.celsius = float((fahrenheit - 32.0) * (0.56))`

`self.fahrenheit = float((celsius * 1.8) + 32.0)`

**EDIT-2:**
This is what your `buttonPressed1` method of `Convert` Class should be:

```
def buttonPressed1(self):
        celsius = self.view.entrySpace.get()
        result = str(self.model.convertToFahrenheit(float(celsius)))
        self.view.outputLabel.config(text=result)
```

And for `buttonPressed2` as:

```
def buttonPressed2(self):
        fahrenheit = self.view.entrySpace.get()
        result = str(self.model.convertToCelsius(float(fahrenheit)))
        self.view.outputLabel.config(text=result)
```

Comment: Hi Khalil, thank you for your response.. I have tried to do what you were doing, but it gives me this error: AttributeError: 'Controller' object has no attribute 'fahrenheit'. I am confused, shouldn't we pass the value in the entrySpace to the convertToFahrenheit? Sorry I am still a beginner in Python :(

Comment: @jaephillseo, update your posted code with the corrections I provided to you, and let us see what's wrong

Comment: @jaephillseo, Check Edit-1 and Edit-2

Comment: Thank you So much Khalil. I don't know how much I can thank you I hope I can be as good as you one day!

Comment: Glad I was of help .. :)